# Why BLE connection fail

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android BLE App connection to a NINA B1 module.
Most of the time I can do a BLE connection, but sometimes not.
I can't seem to figure out why the connection fails sometimes.

I'm adding two Logcat outputs, one for connection to BLE and another when the connection to BLE fails.
Both log cats were cleared before the BLE connection was made.

Below is when the BLE connection was successful.

```
2021-05-17 09:15:12.311 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
2021-05-17 09:15:12.313 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-05-17 09:15:12.313 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: scan not started yet
2021-05-17 09:15:12.315 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.316 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.318 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.319 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.321 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.323 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:15:12.342 15138-15138/com.example.ble V/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@621fcbe className=com.example.ble.BTLE_Services packageName=com.example.ble intent=null}
2021-05-17 09:15:12.348 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example.ble.BTLE_Services@6130c6c, flags=0, startId=1
2021-05-17 09:15:12.463 15138-15138/com.example.ble V/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@f9eecb1 className=com.example.ble.Service_BTLE_GATT packageName=com.example.ble intent=null}
2021-05-17 09:15:12.469 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example.ble.Service_BTLE_GATT@49580e9, flags=0, startId=1
2021-05-17 09:15:12.577 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: CC:F9:57:90:41:4C, auto: false
2021-05-17 09:15:12.577 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2021-05-17 09:15:12.578 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=fe08736c-d7a1-4ec0-864f-342adbcbff00
2021-05-17 09:15:12.581 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: Trying to create a new connection.
2021-05-17 09:15:12.581 15138-15151/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
2021-05-17 09:15:14.413 15138-15150/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7 device=CC:F9:57:90:41:4C
2021-05-17 09:15:14.417 15138-15150/com.example.ble I/Service_BTLE_GATT: Connected to GATT server.
2021-05-17 09:15:14.417 15138-15150/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: CC:F9:57:90:41:4C
2021-05-17 09:15:14.420 15138-15150/com.example.ble I/Service_BTLE_GATT: Attempting to start service discovery:true
2021-05-17 09:15:14.464 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{2bc42a5 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@b28bca
2021-05-17 09:15:14.472 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7e8639e000
2021-05-17 09:15:14.475 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{af3bad2 Toast,ident = 3}
2021-05-17 09:15:14.483 15138-15150/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=CC:F9:57:90:41:4C Status=0
2021-05-17 09:15:14.507 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7e8639e000 initialize window=0x7e719b1000, title=Toast
2021-05-17 09:15:14.507 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7e719b1000)
                                                                                                                                              
2021-05-17 09:15:14.507 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7e719b1000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:15:14.508 15138-15167/com.example.ble W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
2021-05-17 09:15:14.510 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-05-17 09:15:14.520 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: readCharacteristic() - uuid: 2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703
2021-05-17 09:15:14.522 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703 enable: true
2021-05-17 09:15:14.531 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 156, 0, 20, 58
2021-05-17 09:15:14.532 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7e6ee33980) (w:397 h:95 s:400 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:15:14.539 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7e6ee34d00) (w:397 h:95 s:400 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:15:14.648 15138-15143/com.example.ble I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=202KB, data=230KB
2021-05-17 09:15:14.650 15138-15143/com.example.ble I/art: After code cache collection, code=182KB, data=168KB
2021-05-17 09:15:14.701 15138-15151/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead() - Device=CC:F9:57:90:41:4C handle=25 Status=0
2021-05-17 09:15:14.726 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: writeDescriptor() - uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
2021-05-17 09:15:15.052 15138-15150/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onDescriptorWrite() - Device=CC:F9:57:90:41:4C handle=26
2021-05-17 09:15:16.463 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e719b1000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:15:16.470 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7e6ee33980) (w:397 h:95 s:400 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:15:16.470 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7e6ee34d00) (w:397 h:95 s:400 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:15:16.470 15138-15167/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e719b1000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:15:16.478 15138-15138/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{2bc42a5 V.E...... ........ 0,0-397,95}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@b28bca
```

Below is when the BLE connection was unsuccessful.

```
2021-05-17 09:19:22.731 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
2021-05-17 09:19:22.732 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
2021-05-17 09:19:22.733 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothAdapter: scan not started yet
2021-05-17 09:19:22.735 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.738 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.742 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.744 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.748 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.751 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothDevice: getName: name = 043002aaa
2021-05-17 09:19:22.821 15422-15422/com.example.ble V/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@430c779 className=com.example.ble.BTLE_Services packageName=com.example.ble intent=null}
2021-05-17 09:19:22.832 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example.ble.BTLE_Services@6eb11f, flags=0, startId=1
2021-05-17 09:19:22.857 15422-15422/com.example.ble V/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@35a8358 className=com.example.ble.Service_BTLE_GATT packageName=com.example.ble intent=null}
2021-05-17 09:19:22.861 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.example.ble.Service_BTLE_GATT@f2a6570, flags=0, startId=1
2021-05-17 09:19:22.882 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: CC:F9:57:90:41:4C, auto: false
2021-05-17 09:19:22.882 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2021-05-17 09:19:22.883 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=6f17fddb-9ffd-421b-a3b0-59d415dd51ae
2021-05-17 09:19:22.886 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/Service_BTLE_GATT: Trying to create a new connection.
2021-05-17 09:19:22.887 15422-15435/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
2021-05-17 09:19:23.857 15422-15435/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=7 device=CC:F9:57:90:41:4C
2021-05-17 09:19:23.857 15422-15435/com.example.ble I/Service_BTLE_GATT: Disconnected from GATT server.
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
2021-05-17 09:19:23.903 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{128689c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@b28bca
2021-05-17 09:19:23.905 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7e8639e000
2021-05-17 09:19:23.906 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{994ae2b Toast,ident = 3}
2021-05-17 09:19:23.911 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2021-05-17 09:19:23.911 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=7
2021-05-17 09:19:23.940 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7e719bc000)
2021-05-17 09:19:23.940 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7e8639e000 initialize window=0x7e719bc000, title=Toast
2021-05-17 09:19:23.940 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7e719bc000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:19:23.941 15422-15447/com.example.ble W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
2021-05-17 09:19:23.943 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                              
2021-05-17 09:19:23.955 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 60, 0, 115, 253
2021-05-17 09:19:23.957 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7e6ee32f00) (w:485 h:95 s:496 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:19:23.963 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7e6ee65740) (w:485 h:95 s:496 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:19:24.111 15422-15427/com.example.ble I/art: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int)
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                             
2021-05-17 09:19:25.902 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e719bc000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:19:25.904 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7e6ee32f00) (w:485 h:95 s:496 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:19:25.905 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0x7e6ee65740) (w:485 h:95 s:496 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
2021-05-17 09:19:25.905 15422-15447/com.example.ble D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e719bc000,api=1)
2021-05-17 09:19:25.923 15422-15422/com.example.ble D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{128689c V.E...... ........ 0,0-485,95}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@b28bca
```

Can you point me to some info in the Logcat that might help me why the connection fails?

Marinus

Comment: You may want to check the Bluetooth log: [AOSP - Bluetooth Debugging Options](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-options) Also check: [Android BluetoothGatt - status 133 - register callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25330938/295004)

Comment: ThankYou its meaningful, still have to sit and figure out what exactly is happening