# Bluetooth GATT disconnect onConnectionStateChange not called

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to implement my own timeout on my bluetooth GATT services by schedule a timer and call [`BluetoothGatt.disconnect()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java#BluetoothGatt.disconnect%28%29) manually. But the callback is not called like what usually happen if the disconnect is triggered from the remote devices. There is also a log from the `BluetoothGatt` that the disconnect function is called

```
D/BluetoothGatt﹕ cancelOpen() - device: 00:07:80:04:1A:5A
```

and this is my code to disconnect

```
private void scheduleDisconnect() {
    isTimerRunning = true;
    disconnectTimer = new Timer();
    disconnectTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isTimerRunning = false;
            disconnect();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Why is `onConnectionStateChange` not called?
It's working well for another callback and action

Comment: I faced to the same issue. It is so random. I call both disconnect() and then close() method. The onConnectionStateChange called for sometime but not always.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110295/difference-between-close-and-disconnect-in-android-bluetooth-4-0-api

Answer (score 2):

Is your disconnect() method closing the connection as well? Only call BluetoothGatt.close() when you are done with the device, or else your callbacks will be [unregistered](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java).

Comment: I could kiss you! This was my problem. Thanks a bunch! I was calling my close method inside of my disconnect method so it "unregistered" before it made the call.

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect my device, I use the gatt link of the device and I use the methods BluetoothGatt.disconnect() and BluetoothGatt.close().

This worked, but didn't call onConnectionStateChange(), because I close the flux.