# How to use go-ble to connect from android to linux

Tags: android, linux, go, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement a BLE connection between two devices:

- A Linux app, as the server, that must advertise services and characteristics
- An Android smartphone, as the client, that must connect to the server and read characteristics

The issue comes from my Linux app. When I connect my smartphone to my laptop using my android app and bluetoothctl, it works like a charm. However, when I do the same with my Linux app instead of bluetoothctl, it doesn't works (it actually does, but very rarely).

As my Linux app is written in Go, I use [go-ble](https://github.com/go-ble/ble) as the bluetooth package. I have the same issue with their [minimal code sample](https://github.com/go-ble/ble/tree/master/examples/basic/server), this is the reason I don't write more code here, but I can't figure out why.

I think I just don't know how to use their library correctly, but [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-ble/ble#section-documentation) isn't very explicit, so if anyone could help...

---

EDIT

On my smartphone, when using my apps, I see the laptop when scanning, so The HCI device is up. But when attempting to connect with [`connectGatt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)), I get a 133 status code, which is `GATT_ERROR`.

One probable issue, is I'm not closing the connection, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110295/difference-between-close-and-disconnect), but then how could it works with bluetoothctl?

Comment: What does not work when you try to connect to your Go App? Do you get any error messages on your Smartphone?

Comment: Just edited the post :)

Comment: Error 133 is a common generic error, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65662801/7473793). It happens for me more often on older android versions and I always just try to connect again until it connects

Comment: Solved my issue, using the 4th argument of `gattConnect`, with BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE, now it's working fine. So the issue came from my Android app

Comment: Perfect! You could answer your own question if you like ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetoothctl is a bluetooth client working either with BLE and BR\EDR bluetooth. It was working because my android app was connecting through "Classic Bluetooth" with `gattConnect`.

I solved it by specifying the transport protocol to use, replacing:

```
device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)
```

with:

```
device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
```